# for loop fortran issue

Tags: loops, fortran

I am trying to convert a particular fortran 77 code into python.
I got stuck at the following fortan 77 code line:

```
do 90 j = 1,7
```

I googled and found out that upper line can be translated as a for loop from 1 to 7. But I do not understand what `90` is?
What does `90` represent?

Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`90` is the label of the final statement in the `do` loop. Typically the final statement is a `CONTINUE`.

See http://www.obliquity.com/computer/fortran/do.html for more details.